# Encrypted content from BufferReader

Tags: android, ssl, https, inputstream

I have this situation: there is a Jersey rest web service working via HTTPS. I'm working on an Android code that will POST Json to that service and read response. I managed to connect, from API log i can see that call has been received and no errors are displayed, i also get data in the "InputStream" of the connection, but data is encrypted! Even when i try using plain HTTP connection and run web service in HTTP mode result is the same.

What confuses me is that equal cURL request produces proper output without any issues... Where am i wrong? This is the code i'm using:

```
        URL url = new URL("https://myServer:8780/api/<apicall>");
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Create the SSL connection
        SSLContext sc;
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, null, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // set Timeout and method
        conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        // Add any data you wish to post here
        String json = "{\"test\":\"hello\"}";


        byte[] bytes = json.getBytes("UTF-8");
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(bytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        String result = new String();
        InputStream is = null;
        /*if ("gzip".equals(conn.getContentEncoding()))
            is = new GZIPInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); THIS WOULD FAIL WITH ERROR MESSAGE THAT CONTENT IS NOT IN GZIP FORMAT!
        else*/
            is = conn.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result += inputLine;
        }
```

In the same time, this cURL call (i'm using Linux) works perfectly and returns expected JSON response from the server:

```
curl -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip' -X POST https://myServer:8780/api/<apicall> -d '{"test":"hello"}'
```

**EDIT** Issue was caused by my server using both "Content-encoding: gzip" and "Transfer-encoding: gzip". When i removed "Transfer-Encoding" issue was solved!

Comment: So it was never encrypted, it was GZipped, maybe twice.

Comment: Yes, apparently it was Gzipped twice. I was confused when i tried using GzipInputStream i got an error that content is not in GZip format...